# Можно ли как-то деструкторизировать переменные kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Я не уверен что я правильно использую термин "деструктуризация", но везде то что я хочу сделать называют именно так. В java можно было написать например так:

```
Integer kind, id, from, draft_id, from_m_id;
```

то есть все переменные можно было записать в одну строку друг за другом и это было нормально. В котлине же нужно каждую переменную писать с новой строки и это не очень удобно. Видел что само понятие деструктуризации в котлине есть такое понятие, но я так и не понял как это сделать. Или же такое нельзя реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Kotlin есть понятие деструктуризации, но оно отличается от того, что Вы пытаетесь сделать.

На самом деле [деструктуризация](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) - это присвоение значения объекта нескольким переменным путём его разбиения на отдельные части.

Если же вернуться к сути Вашего вопроса.

```
Integer kind, id, from, draft_id, from_m_id;
```

Подобный синтаксис, насколько я знаю, в Kotlin не поддерживается.

Comment: я так понимаю я не очень правильно использовал термин)) то есть нужно каждую переменную обьявлять с новой строки и так как в java сделать нет возможности?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Kotlin только так.

Answer (score 3):

Деструктуризация в Котлин происходит следующим образом:

```
data class Person (val name: String, val age: Int)

val person = Person("Thomas", 40)
val (name, age) = person // деструктуризация
```

Вот, что происходит под капотом:

```
val name = person.component1()
val age = person.component2()
```

Если вы хотите просто объявить несколько переменных в одной строке, то можете сделать так:

```
var (p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) = List(3) { 0 }
```

Это создаст 3 переменные типа Int, а с помощью List(<кол-во переменных>) мы присвоим каждой переменной значение 0.